# Suction pipe insulation

Tags: hvac

I’m a new home owner. I noticed that insulation on my suction pipe was cracking. I wasn’t sure what insulation to use rubber or foam. I decided to use rubber, was I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have always used rubber insulation when I can find it. It's a much better insulation and lasts much longer. Foam seems more readily available, maybe because it's cheaper.

Comment: Maybe I'm being a bit dense here, but what the heck is a "suction pipe"?

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  In an AC unit he larger line typically carries a cool gas and is insulated. This is commonly referred to as the suction line, but it is also called the return line or vapor line.

Comment: Thanks very much, JACK!  I learn so much here.  It's also fascinating to learn of the different terms throughout the world describing the same thing.   2 examples:  in the UK an outlet is called a socket. A grounding conductor is called an Earth wire.  Many more examples but don't want to waste ppls. time here.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  You're not wasting anyone's time.  We're all learning and enjoying  new friends... Stay safe out there.

Comment: @george Anderson , the grounded vs grounding can get even more confusing , then some call PE potential earth. But the suction pipe is the common name for the low pressure return in a compressed gas Refridgeration system (most common type with an outside compressor). As far as the insulation neoprene foam rubber is what most systems are built with it lasts longer and actually seals were foam normally used on water pipes can become water saturated more easily.+